# Insert foreign key id from value

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have two tables.

```
            Table "public.part"
      Column       |          Type          |
-------------------+------------------------+
 id                | bigint                 | 
 part_name         | character varying(255) |
 part_department   | character varying(255) |
 part_manufacturer | character varying(255) | 
 part_model        | character varying(255) |
 part_category     | character varying(255) | 
 part_storage      | character varying(255) | 
 part_description  | character varying(255) | 
 part_stocklimit   | smallint               | 


     Table "public.entry"
     Column     |          Type          |
----------------+------------------------+
 id             | bigint                 | 
 part_id        | bigint                 |
 entry_status   | character(5)           |
 entry_qty      | smallint               |
 entry_desc     | character varying(500) |
 entry_date     | date                   |
 entry_employee | character varying(225)
```

I want to insert data into the entry TABLE. The entry TABLE has part_id which is the FOREIGN KEY of id from part TABLE.

I have a built a from to insert the values for the entry TABLE using PyQt5 and using psycopg2 to run the psql commands in python which looks like this.

[image: GUI for insert data into entry table]

The name label has combobox which gets the list of parts from part TABLE. Now I want to insert the data from the comboBox matching with the id from part TABLE. 
So lets say something like this

```
INSERT INTO entry (part_id, entry_status, entry_qty, entry_desc, entry_date, entry_employee) VALUES
( SELECT id FROM part WHERE part_name=entry_part_name, entry_status, entry_qty, entry_desc, entry_date, entry_employee );
```

Now i have worked out the standard INSERT statement in python which looks like this. But i dont know how to match the id of the part so it can insert the id rather than the part name.

```
    def AddEntry_Data(self):
    self.db = ConnectDatabase()
    entry_part_name = self.comboBoxNewEntryPart.currentText()
    entry_employee = self.comboBoxNewEntryEmployee.currentText()
    entry_status = self.comboBoxNewEntryStatus.currentText()
    entry_quantity = self.spinBoxNewEntryQuantity.value()
    entry_description = self.lineNewEntryDescription.toPlainText()
    entry_date = self.dateNewEntryDate.text()

    try:
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('SAVEPOINT SP1')
        self.cur.execute('''INSERT INTO entry (part_id, entry_status, entry_qty, entry_desc, entry_date, entry_employee) 
                                            VALUES (%s , %s , %s , %s , %s , %s , %s , %s)''', (entry_part_name, entry_status, entry_quantity, entry_description, entry_date, entry_employee))
    except Exception as error:
        self.cur.execute('ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SP1')
        self.AddEntry_reset()
        print(error)
        # self.error_popup("Input Error", error)
    else:
        self.cur.execute('RELEASE SAVEPOINT SP1')
        self.db.commit()
        self.AddEntry_reset()
        self.success_popup("Entry", "New Entry Added.")
    self.db.close
```

One of the way I can think of is select querying the id and store in a variable and pass the variable to insert query.

```
        try:
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('SAVEPOINT SP1')
        self.cur.execute('''SELECT id FROM part WHERE part_name = %s ''', [(entry_part_name,)])
    except Exception as error:
        self.cur.execute('ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SP1')
        self.AddEntry_reset()
        self.error_popup("Input Error", error)
    else:
        fetched_part_id = self.cur.fetchone()
        try:
            self.cur.execute('''INSERT INTO entry (fetched_part_id, entry_status, entry_qty, entry_desc, entry_date, entry_employee)
                                                VALUES (%s , %s , %s , %s , %s , %s)''', (fetch_id, entry_status, entry_quantity, entry_description, entry_date, entry_employee))
        except Exception as error:
            self.cur.execute('ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SP1')
            self.AddEntry_reset()
            self.error_popup("Input Error", error)
        else:
            self.cur.execute('RELEASE SAVEPOINT SP1')
            self.db.commit()
            self.AddEntry_reset()
            self.success_popup("Entry", "New Entry Added.")
    self.db.close()
```

If there is any other simple way to combine the select query within  insert query in python like wise sql command stated at top is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `INSERT INTO ...` and `SELECT`:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO entry (part_id, entry_status, entry_qty, entry_desc, entry_date, entry_employee) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM part WHERE part_name = %s), %s , %s , %s , %s , %s)"""

self.cur.execute(sql, (entry_part_name, entry_status, entry_quantity, entry_description, entry_date, entry_employee))
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. @Maurice Meyer